# How to update a field in Firebase when using a datatable?

Tags: firebase, dart

How can I update a specific field in my `Datatable`. I am using this package: https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_table

When I tap on one item in my `Datatable` it opens a `Dialog`  where I have my `TextController` and a `ElevatedButton` for updating my values. All that seems to work, I click on one item, the right name of that item is stored in my `TextController`. But when I press my button, it's updating some random item in my `Firebase` and not the value that i clicked in the first place.

Here is my code:

```
class _UsersPageState extends State<UsersPage> {

 
  var nameController = TextEditingController();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final UserTableProvider usertablesProvider = Provider.of<UserTableProvider>(context);
    return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: [
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  maxHeight: 700,
                ),
                child: Card(
                  elevation: 1,
                  shadowColor: Colors.black,
                  clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                  child: ResponsiveDatatable(
                    title: TextButton.icon(
                      onPressed: () => {
                        addUserDialog(context),
                      },
                      icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                      label: Text("Legg til bruker"),
                    ),
                    reponseScreenSizes: [ScreenSize.xs],
                    actions: [
                      if (usertablesProvider.isSearch)
                        Expanded(
                            child: TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                hintText: 'Søk på ansattnr..',
                                  prefixIcon: IconButton(
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.cancel),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        setState(() {
                                          usertablesProvider.isSearch = false;
                                        });
                                      }),
                                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () {})),
                              onSubmitted: (value) {
                                usertablesProvider.filterData(value);
                              },
                            )),
                      if (!usertablesProvider.isSearch)
                        IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                usertablesProvider.isSearch = true;
                              });
                            }),

                    ],
                    headers: usertablesProvider.userTableHeader,
                    source: usertablesProvider.source,
                    selecteds: usertablesProvider.selecteds,
                    showSelect: usertablesProvider.showSelect,
                    autoHeight: false,
                    onSort: (value) {
                      setState(() => usertablesProvider.isLoading = true);

                      setState(() {
                        usertablesProvider.sortColumn = value;
                        usertablesProvider.sortAscending = !usertablesProvider.sortAscending;
                        if (usertablesProvider.sortAscending) {
                          usertablesProvider.sourceFiltered.sort((a, b) =>
                              b["${usertablesProvider.sortColumn}"].compareTo(a["${usertablesProvider.sortColumn}"]));
                        } else {
                          usertablesProvider.sourceFiltered.sort((a, b) =>
                              a["${usertablesProvider.sortColumn}"].compareTo(b["${usertablesProvider.sortColumn}"]));
                        }
                        var _rangeTop = usertablesProvider.currentPerPage! < usertablesProvider.sourceFiltered.length
                            ? usertablesProvider.currentPerPage!
                            : usertablesProvider.sourceFiltered.length;
                        usertablesProvider.source = usertablesProvider.sourceFiltered.getRange(0, _rangeTop).toList();
                        usertablesProvider.searchKey = value;

                        usertablesProvider.isLoading = false;
                      });
                    },
                    expanded: usertablesProvider.expanded,
                    sortAscending: usertablesProvider.sortAscending,
                    sortColumn: usertablesProvider.sortColumn,
                    isLoading: usertablesProvider.isLoading,
                    onTabRow: (data){
                      
                      updateUserDialog(context);
                      print(data);

                      nameController.text = data['name'];
                      
                    },
                    onSelect: (value, item) {
                      print("$value  $item ");
                      if (value!) {
                        setState(() => usertablesProvider.selecteds.add(item));
                      } else {
                        setState(
                                () => usertablesProvider.selecteds.removeAt(usertablesProvider.selecteds.indexOf(item)));
                      }
                    },
                    onSelectAll: (value) {
                      if (value!) {
                        setState(() => usertablesProvider.selecteds =
                            usertablesProvider.source.map((entry) => entry).toList().cast());
                      } else {
                        setState(() => usertablesProvider.selecteds.clear());
                      }
                    },
                    footers: [
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                        child: Text("Rader per side:"),
                      ),
                      if (usertablesProvider.perPages.isNotEmpty)
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                          child: DropdownButton<int>(
                            value: usertablesProvider.currentPerPage,
                            items: usertablesProvider.perPages
                                .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem<int>(
                              child: Text("$e"),
                              value: e,
                            ))
                                .toList(),
                            onChanged: (dynamic value) {
                              setState(() {
                                usertablesProvider.currentPerPage = value;
                                usertablesProvider.currentPage = 1;
                                usertablesProvider.resetData();
                              });
                            },
                            isExpanded: false,
                          ),
                        ),
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                        child:
                        Text("${usertablesProvider.currentPage} - ${usertablesProvider.currentPerPage} of ${usertablesProvider.total}"),
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                          size: 16,
                        ),
                        onPressed: usertablesProvider.currentPage == 1
                            ? null
                            : () {
                          var _nextSet = usertablesProvider.currentPage - usertablesProvider.currentPerPage!;
                          setState(() {
                            usertablesProvider.currentPage = _nextSet > 1 ? _nextSet : 1;
                            usertablesProvider.resetData(start: usertablesProvider.currentPage - 1);
                          });
                        },
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios, size: 16),
                        onPressed: usertablesProvider.currentPage + usertablesProvider.currentPerPage! - 1 > usertablesProvider.total
                            ? null
                            : () {
                          var _nextSet = usertablesProvider.currentPage + usertablesProvider.currentPerPage!;

                          setState(() {
                            usertablesProvider.currentPage = _nextSet < usertablesProvider.total
                                ? _nextSet
                                : usertablesProvider.total - usertablesProvider.currentPerPage!;
                            usertablesProvider.resetData(start: _nextSet - 1);
                          });
                        },
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ])
    );

  }

  updateUserDialog(BuildContext context){
    return showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) {
      return Dialog(
        child: Container(
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 600,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Text('Endre bruker', style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                ),),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                TextField(
                  controller: nameController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Navn',
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)
                      )
                  ),
             
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)
                      )
                  ),
                ),
               
                ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      var name = nameController.text.trim();
              

                      FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

                      FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

                      User? user = auth.currentUser;



                      await firebaseFirestore.collection('users').doc(user!.uid).update({
                        'navn': name,
               

                      });


                      nameController.text = '';


                    },
                    child: const Text('Save')),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
```

```
    class UserTableProvider with ChangeNotifier {

  List<DatatableHeader> userTableHeader = [
    DatatableHeader(
        text: "Ansattnr",
        value: "empnumber",
        show: true,
        flex: 1,
        sortable: true,
        textAlign: TextAlign.left),
    DatatableHeader(
        text: "Navn",
        value: "name",
        show: true,
        flex: 6,
        sortable: true,
        textAlign: TextAlign.left),
    DatatableHeader(
        text: "Epost",
        value: "email",
        show: true,
        flex: 4,
        sortable: true,
        textAlign: TextAlign.left),
    DatatableHeader(
        text: "",
        value: "uid",
        show: false,
        sortable: true,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center),
    DatatableHeader(
        text: "Tlf",
        value: "tlfnumber",
        show: true,
        flex: 2,
        sortable: true,
        textAlign: TextAlign.left),
    DatatableHeader(
        text: "Eget verktøy",
        value: "owntool",
        show: false,
        sortable: true,
        textAlign: TextAlign.left),

  ];

  final List<int> perPages = [10, 20, 50, 100];
  int total = 100;
  int? currentPerPage = 10;
  int currentPage = 1;
  List<bool>? expanded;
  String? searchKey = "empnumber";

  bool isSearch = false;
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> sourceOriginal = [];
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> sourceFiltered = [];
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> source = [];
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> selecteds = [];
  // ignore: unused_field
  final String selectableKey = "id";

  String? sortColumn;
  bool sortAscending = true;
  bool isLoading = true;
  final bool showSelect = true;

  final UserServices _userServices = UserServices();
  List<UserModel> _users = <UserModel>[];
  List<UserModel> get users => _users;

  Future _loadFromFirebase() async {
    _users = await _userServices.getAllUsers();

  }

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> _getUsersData() {
    isLoading = true;
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> temps = [];
    var i = users.length;
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print(i);
    }
    // ignore: unused_local_variable
    for (UserModel userData in users) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(userData.name);
      }
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(userData.email);
      }
      temps.add({
        "empnumber": userData.empnumber,
        "email": userData.email,
        "name": userData.name,
        "uid": userData.uid,
        "owntool": userData.owntool,
        "tlfnumber": userData.tlfnumber,
      });
      i++;
    }


    return temps;
  }

  _initData() async {
    await _loadFromFirebase();
    mockPullData();
    notifyListeners();

  }

  mockPullData() async {
    expanded = List.generate(currentPerPage!, (index) => false);

    isLoading = true;
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3)).then((value) {
      sourceOriginal.clear();
      sourceOriginal.addAll(_getUsersData());
      sourceFiltered = sourceOriginal;
      total = sourceFiltered.length;
      source = sourceFiltered.getRange(0, _users.length).toList();
      isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  resetData({start: 0}) async {
    isLoading = true;
    var expandedLen =
    total - start < currentPerPage! ? total - start : currentPerPage;
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 0)).then((value) {
      expanded = List.generate(expandedLen as int, (index) => false);
      source.clear();
      source = sourceFiltered.getRange(start, start + expandedLen).toList();
      isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  filterData(value) {
    isLoading = true;

    try {
      if (value == "" || value == null) {
        source = sourceOriginal;
      } else {
        sourceFiltered = sourceOriginal
            .where((data) => data[searchKey!]
            .toString()
            .toLowerCase()
            .contains(value.toString().toLowerCase()))
            .toList();
      }

      total = sourceFiltered.length;
      var _rangeTop = total < currentPerPage! ? total : currentPerPage!;
      expanded = List.generate(_rangeTop, (index) => false);
      source = sourceFiltered.getRange(0, _rangeTop).toList();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    isLoading = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }


  UserTableProvider.init() {
    _initData();
  }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to recreate your exact view. can you please share the code from your UserTableProvider class?

Comment: Hi, offcourse, will do that right away.

Comment: Alright then, waiting on you. You can edit the post to add it. below the UsersPage State code

Comment: I've added it now

Comment: Alright, let me check this out.

Comment: Okay ive tried out your code, and it seems updating the firestore database is working just fine. It does update field in the database with the key specified, with the value entered in the text field.

Comment: In my understanding of your code, the dialog always edits the value of name(navn) in the firestore database. And that seems okay.

Comment: The problem i see with it, is that for every row you click on, even if its not name(navn), the dialog always updates the value of name(navn) in the firestore database. Do you intend to have the dialog edit the field clicked on even if it's not name?

Comment: Hi, name is only one field. I have other fields under the same document. But just to simplify it I only chose to update the 'name'. Now when I run the code it does update the name, but not the right document. So it's not updating the row that was clicked.

Comment: Could it be that in my `updatedialog` method it doesn't know what row I clicked? So maybe I have to pass the ID of the row from `onTap`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245570/discussion-between-tonny-bawembye-and-alexander).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the user id you are using to update the firestore document, the current user's id not the user id from the data.

Please edit your `updateUserDialog` method, add the data as a parameter for the function. Something like `updateUserDialog(BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> data)`.
This will avail the whole data Map within the method. This will expose the uid for you to use to update the right document. You can then pass uid from the data Map as the doc as shown below.

```
await firebaseFirestore.collection('users').doc(userId).update({
  'navn': name,
});
```

For the snippet above, the `uid` is stored in a variable `userId`.

Below is the complete updated method you can work with.

```
updateUserDialog(BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    nameController.text = data['name'];
    String userId = data['uid'].toString();

    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return Dialog(
          child: Container(
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 600,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  const Text(
                    'Endre bruker',
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    controller: nameController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Navn',
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey))),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        var name = nameController.text.trim();

                        FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore =
                            FirebaseFirestore.instance;

                      
                        await firebaseFirestore
                            .collection('users')
                            .doc(userId)
                            .update({
                          'navn': name,
                        });

                        nameController.text = '';
                      },
                      child: const Text('Save')),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

You might as well update your `onTabRow` function to

```
onTabRow: (data) {
   updateUserDialog(context, data);
},
```

That should solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much!!, this was the solution :)